# How out of date is the "blog tutorial" video on the ruby on rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hay, with the release of Ruby on Rails 3 soon, I thought I'd dive back into a bit of Ruby on Rails programming. I missed out version 2 of rails and had only previously been using 1.2

So i hopped on the video tutorial and worked through it. I just wanted to know how out of date is the video? Does all the theory in that video, and ways of working still apply today? Or is it out of date and there's better ways to programming?

The movie in question is http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like he's using Rails 2.2.1, which is close to current production (2.3.5, possibly 2.3.6). The screencast seems current enough - if it wasn't I would expect the presenter (Ryan Bates) would update it; he's very good like that. (And many, if not all, of Ryan's 200+ [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) are highly relevant)

Rails 3 is going to be significantly different, however.